# How to force-cancel a running download?

Tags: downloading

I have started a download using [Icon Downloader for NT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle.iconDownloader&hl=en) that doesn't look like it will ever finish. In my notification area, it has survived two reboots and the uninstallation of the app. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: God I hate download manager. It's possibly the buggiest piece of software on Android even on ICS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually if you long press on the downloading item in download manager there's an option to delete it, thus stopping the download.

If this doesn't work you can clear the Download Manager's data.

```
Settings -> Apps -> All Tab -> Download Manager
```

Here press force stop, than clear data. Now reboot.

Comment: For others reference, this is now `Settings >> General Tab, Application Manager >> ALL tab, Download Manager`

Comment: It appears that doing a reboot is optional now, well at least in Lollipop and above.

Comment: This is only right if the app downloads through the download manager. If it does it through the app that needs updating instead, then force stopping download manager won't stop the update from occurring.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for resurrecting an old thread but I just had the same problem of needing to stop a download and solved the problem by activating Aeroplane Mode.

A less invasive solution and more easily reached in the UI - for anyone else ending up here from Google (like I did :-))

Comment: In my case (Android 4.4.4) it stops but as soon as it finds a working connection again it restarts the download

Answer (score 3):

Long press the notification and select "App Info". This will take you to the application which is responsible for the download, which you can then force stop.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as this stops the app causing the conflict.

Comment: In my case (Android 4.4.4) it stops but then the app seems to respawn and restarts the download

Answer (score 2):

In Android 4.4 (KitKat) / Galaxy S5, go to Settings > Under Applications section > Application Manager > All. Look for Download manager. Force stop, Clear data, and Clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to cancel a download in Android Lollipop is to disconnect from any internet connection, ie turn off WiFi or mobile data. Another method would be to enable airplane mode; either methods would cause the files to timeout. Then you could delete the partially downloaded file..

Rudy